# 学習曲線から見る過学習もしくは学習不足の判断について

Tags: python3, 機械学習

表題の件ですが、現在隠れマルコフモデル(HMM)で時系列データの自動判別を試みていますが、過学習の疑いがあるため質問しました。
サンプル数は60でtrue/falseの2値分類の学習なのですが、サンプル数別の検証結果とテスト結果によるaccuracyの曲線が以下のようにプロットされました。

[image]

お聞きしたい事としては、青線が検証データ・緑線がテストデータでのスコアなのですが、テストデータが検証データのスコアを上回ることってあるのでしょうか？あるとした場合、この状況はどちらに当てはまるのでしょうか...。どの参考書を見ても、
検証スコア＞テストスコア
なためここに質問させて頂きます。
ざっくりですみません、どなたかよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 検証スコア＜テストスコア となることもあると思いますが、ソースコードが誤ってそうな気がします。ソースコードを載せてみたら、何かいいアドバイス得られるかもしれませんね。

Comment: コメント有難うございます。
やはり学習段階でミスがあるようでした。